# {"error_description":"expired access/refresh token","error":"invalid_grant"}

Tags: connected-apps

I am getting `{"error_description":"expired access/refresh token","error":"invalid_grant"}` error when I am trying to connect with connected app.

However, when I change the Username and password to different user it's working fine...Both the user have the same profile.. I don't know why I am getting this error

```
curl https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=3MVG9OI03ecbG2Vosy6al2ZUF1eKyCkOJo*************LbEZbNaHYweri5a71CEQX739A2gAHs5F4iE9I" -d "client_secret=32622********943676193" -d "username=int*******ion.user@***.com.prmsb1" -d "password=1*************$123"
```

If I change the username and password to different , it works perfectly fine..

Comment: Two questions:
1) When was the last refresh of that environment/sandbox?
2) I assume you have requested a new token for that User?

Comment: On **Setup | Manage Apps | Connected Apps**, what do you see for **Permitted Users**?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'm having a similar issue.